# using multiple static time intervals in where clause

Tags: postgresql

I want to specify three time intervals, am I doing this correctly?

```
where 

(time_created between '2022-06-27 13:00:00' and '2022-06-27 20:00:00'

or

time_created between '2022-06-28 13:00:00' and '2022-06-28 20:00:00'

or

time_created between'2022-06-29 13:00:00' and '2022-06-29 20:00:00')
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: It executed, but I am not sure about the results.

Comment: Create a specific test case where you know the results in advance. Make sure it contains rows that should be selected and others that should not be selected. Then run your query against that data.

Comment: can you please let me know if the current query will return true if the time lies in either of the 3 intervals? I think so